# Strange space in Lubuntu desktop

Tags: lubuntu, panel

As you can see on the image below, I have got a large space in the panel. In the preferences panel of the panel there is nothing here between the notification area and the battery control applet.

How can I delete this ugly space ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which version of Lubuntu you are using but let me say that I encountered this problem in Lubuntu 12.04 **but not in Lubuntu 12.10**.

It was discussed quite a bit over here: [Empty spaces in lxpanel when using xfce4-power-manager](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2012-February/000335.html).

A relevant bug appear to be: [empty space between time applet and nm-applet](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/846878).

Comment: Actually, I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I installed the lubuntu-desktop package in order to see if I like or not this desktop environment. Thus I will wait to update to 12.10 ;) !